# how to import package in html file in scala on play

Tags: html, scala, import, playframework

I am working on a web project using scala on play framework. I will need to import an external package to use the classes defined in it. I have no problem to do it in my .scala file. But I don't find a way to import that package in view/..scala.html file. As a result, when it is built, it reports error not found the definition of that class. I tried to import that package like the below way.

@import myPackage._

But it doesn't seems to work.

How can I do that?

Comment: `@import com.example.MyClass` works fine for me. I can't be sure of the problem with you example. What was the specific compilation error? Does the class even exist in the classpath ( er... in the project )?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use any method of model or controller or any of your package you can try

```
<span>@models.modelName.getName(userId)</span>
```

i have not tried your way